# Image does not display with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code ([view.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q38hu7wmiyujc4j/view.php))

and then I have php code ([mysql_connect.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x84cn0typiu0na6/mysql_connect.php))

and MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `no` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `course` text NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `picture` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

the problem in displaying image. why i can't display my image?

Comment: You should just include the relevant code in the question (rather than links to everything). It will make it easier for people to understand what you are tryin to do!

Comment: I just checked the link you provided then why down vote?

Comment: Can you include an example of what is being outputted as a source for one of your images?

Comment: @Paddyd read the question and see the link the link is https://www.dropbox.com/s/q38hu7wmiyujc4j/view.php and if you see he is missing something and it should show images now.

Comment: Don't store your images in the database. Store the LINKS to the images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 echo"<tr>";   
                    echo"<td>" .$test['ref']."</td>";
                    echo"<td>" .$test['course']."</td>";
                    echo"<td>" .$test['name']."</td>";
                    echo"<td>Rp.".$test['price']."</td>";
                    echo"<td>" .$test['description']."</td>"; ?>
                    <td><img src='http://mysite.com/image/<?php echo $test['picture']; ?>' height="100" width="100" /> <?php echo "</td>";
                    echo"<td> <a href ='edit.php?ref=$id'><center>Edit</a></td>"; 
                    echo"<td> <a href ='del.php?ref=$id'><center>Delete</a></td>";
                    echo"<td></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: if you are using php to serve images then you should make a file like image.php and then when show the image do image.php?id=<?php echo $test['picture']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Relevant code is this:

```
echo"<td>";?><img src='image/".$test['picture']."' height="100" width="100" /> <?php echo "</td>";
```

That's not how you insert images in HTML. Instead, you need to:

1. Write a script that retrieves the image body
2. Link such script in the `src` attribute

Answer (score 0):

why you close with php tag ?> when you need the image for each tr so you need to make like this:

```
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

                $id = $test['ref']; 


                echo"<tr>";   
                echo"<td>" .$test['ref']."</td>";
                echo"<td>" .$test['course']."</td>";
                echo"<td>" .$test['name']."</td>";
                echo"<td>Rp.".$test['price']."</td>";
                echo"<td>" .$test['description']."</td>"; 
                echo"<td><img src='image/".$test['picture']."' height='100' width='100' />";
                echo "</td>";
                echo"<td> <a href ='edit.php?ref=$id'><center>Edit</a></td>"; 
                echo"<td> <a href ='del.php?ref=$id'><center>Delete</a></td>";
                echo"<td></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture column is BLOB. This means you cannot display it directly in the  tag. You need to have a php script that will display the image and link to that script in the src attribute.

**img.php**

```
$no = $_GET['no'];

// fetch the record from the database into $image (be careful at sql injection)

// Check the mime type of the image and add the appropriate header
//header('Content-Type: image/gif');
//header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

echo $image['picture'];
```

**Then display the image like this:**

```
<img src="img.php?no=<?php echo $dbRecord['no']; ?>" />
```

The code is not complete but you should get the idea.